# Angular JS ng-options selecting list from JSON

Tags: angularjs, json, ng-options, angular-chosen

I'm tryin to use a `select` with `ng-options` to populate my dropdown. This is my JSON

`{
  "Food": [
    {
      "Name": Apple,
      "HealthCondition": [
        {
        "Name": "High Blood Pressure",
        "Eat": null
        },
        {
        "Name": "High Cholesterol",
        "Eat": null
        },
        {
        "Name": "Heart Disease",
        "Eat": null
        },
        {
        "Name": "Osteoporosis",
        "Eat": null
        },
        {
        "Name": "Digestive Disorder",
        "Eat": null
        }
    ]
    }`

And this is my select `<select  class="chosen-select" ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="x.HealthCondition for x in myResults.Food" multiple chosen></select>` and the result I'm getting is `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

I'm trying to get a list of the Health Condition Names! Any help would be greatly appreciated. Stumped on this for hours. I'm using the [Angular Chosen](http://adityasharat.github.io/angular-chosen/) directive. This is working correctly if I just use the Name field like `x.Name` but I want to get HealthCondition Name.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some Observations :**

- Your JSON is not valid. **`Apple`** should be a string against the **`name`** key.
- You are iterating the `Food` array in `ng-options` it should be `HealthCondition`.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.jsonObj = {
  "Food": [
    {
      "Name": "Apple",
      "HealthCondition": [
        {
        "Name": "High Blood Pressure",
        "Eat": null
        },
        {
        "Name": "High Cholesterol",
        "Eat": null
        },
        {
        "Name": "Heart Disease",
        "Eat": null
        },
        {
        "Name": "Osteoporosis",
        "Eat": null
        },
        {
        "Name": "Digestive Disorder",
        "Eat": null
        }
    ]
}]};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select class="chosen-select" ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="x.Name as x.Name for x in jsonObj.Food[0].HealthCondition" multiple chosen></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Rohit ! This worked! The only thing I did was change jsonObj to my scopes name myResults.

Comment: @kurtg Can you please mark it as a correct so that it will be useful for others also.

Comment: ok I did that, sorry pretty new to stackoverflow, didn't see how but clicked the check between the up and down arrows and that seemed to do it! thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try `<select class="chosen-select" ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="x.Name as x.Name for x in myResults.Food.HealthCondition" multiple chosen></select>`

Comment: should be <select class="chosen-select" ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="x.Name as Name for x in myResults.Food.HealthCondition" multiple chosen></select>

Comment: Not really, check the [documentation](http://adityasharat.github.io/angular-chosen/) of the used directive.

Comment: thanks @MonikaBozhinova but that didn't work for me. Rohit's solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your data is not able to be used for ng-options in its current format. You need to reduce the available HealthConditions down into a single array instead of multiple objects with a HealthCondition array as a property.

In your controller you will need to map the data to a single array like so:

```
$scope.HealthConditions = myResults.reduce(function(arr, result){ 
    for(var i in result.HealthCondition){
        arr.push(result.HealthCondition[i]);
    }
    return arr;
}, []);
```

And then in your view use the following:

```
<select class="chosen-select" ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="x.Name for x in HealthConditions" multiple chosen></select>
```

Comment: Thanks Teddy but this didn't work. @Rohit's solution worked for me. He suggested this `x.Name as x.Name for x in myResults.Food[0].HealthCondition` in my ng-options.You're not the first person to tell me that it wouldn't work with my JSON structured as it is so I was surprised this worked.

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution. I imagine others like myself figured your data would have more than just one food element in the results and you would want to display all possible health conditions for every food item.